# Cycle through spans inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, cycle

I'd like to be able to click on a div and have it cycle through spans inside the div. I can get it to work with the code below, but I'd like to have several of these on a page together that work independently (so they only cycle through their own children). The click should advance both text slideshows, but with independent contents.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var divs = $('.timezones span').hide(),
    i = 0;

  function cycle() {
    divs.fadeOut(0).eq(i).fadeIn(0);
    i = ++i % divs.length;
  };
  cycle()
  $('.timezones').click(function() {
    cycle()
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timezones">
  <span>9am PDT</span>
  <span>10am MDT</span>
  <span>11am CDT</span>
  <span>12pm EST</span>
</div>

<div class="timezones">
  <span>5pm PDT</span>
  <span>6pm MDT</span>
  <span>7pm CDT</span>
  <span>8pm EST</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than having to store index variables I typically look for the active one within the current  parent container and use `next()`. When the active next doesn't exist you revert to the `first()`

Something like:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function cycle() {
    // `this` is the .timezone element event occurred on
    var $spans = $(this).children(),
      $active = $spans.filter(':visible'),
      $next = $active.next().length ? $active.next() : $spans.first();

    $active.fadeOut(function() {
      $next.fadeIn()
    });

  }

  $('.timezones').click(cycle).find('span:eq(0)').show();

});
```

```css
.timezones span {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timezones">
  <span>9am PDT</span>
  <span>10am MDT</span>
  <span>11am CDT</span>
  <span>12pm EST</span>
</div>

<div class="timezones">
  <span>5pm PDT</span>
  <span>6pm MDT</span>
  <span>7pm CDT</span>
  <span>8pm EST</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great, but is it possible for the click event to cycle both divs? So if you advance in one div, you also advance in another. Thanks!

Comment: Oh you want all .timesones instances to advance regardless of which one is clicked? That was not entirely clear. If that's the case why not just have a single "Advance All" button rather than clicking anywhere?

Comment: Yes, everything should advance. An advance all button would work too.

Comment: Then you need to revamp using `$('.timezones').each...` and use the code I have inside cycle function for each of the instances. Within `each` callbck `this` will be the current iteration timezones element and all that code inside the cycle function should work inside the each callback

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var divs = $('.timezones span');
    i = 0;

  function cycle(selectedDiv) {
    selectedDiv.fadeOut(0).eq(i).fadeIn(0);
    i = ++i % selectedDiv.length;
  };

  $('.timezones').click(function() {

    cycle( $(this).children('span'));
  })
});
```

The below line of code will able to help you find out the span of clicked div

$(this).children('span');

Comment: Using a global `i` for all timezones is going to be problematic. Note *"so they only cycle through their own children"* in OP

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var divs = $('.timezones span').hide(), i = 0; 
function cycle(elm){ 
let spans= elm.find('span');
spans.fadeOut(0).eq(i).fadeIn(0); 
i = ++i % spans.length;
 }; 

cycle() 

$('.timezones').each(
function() { 
cycle($(this)) 
}) 


});
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


        $( ".timezones" ).click(function() {
          $( ".timezones " ).each(function( i ) {
            var $spans = $(this).children(),
              $active = $spans.filter(':visible'),
              $next = $active.next().length ? $active.next() : $spans.first();

            $active.fadeOut(0, function() {
              $next.fadeIn(0)
            });
          });
        });    

        $('.timezones').find('span:eq(0)').show();

    });
```